# How to do you convert POJO to JSON and vice-versa using the Java Mongo API only (without storing first)

Tags: java, mongodb

My mobile app receives a JSON document from my server, but then my app sends it back to the server with additional fields populated, some fields modified.

Upon receipt at the server I can convert this JSON string to a generic Mongo Document and dump it into the database, I can then read it back as a POJO.  This is wasteful, all I want to do is convert the JSON to a POJO using the mongo API, manipulate the data a little, then store it.

Likewise I sometimes don't want to query as the generic Document but a specific typed POJO then create the Document / JSON from it after manipulating it in a type-safe way.

Ideally I'd like to support parsing a list of documents too.  Using the **Java Mongo API** is it possible to

1. Convert a POJO to a JSON String
2. Convert a JSON string (or Document) to POJO
3. Convert a JSON array to a List
4. Convert a List to a JSON List of documents

Please note that I'm trying to avoid using JAX-RS / JAXB or Spring, or other third party libraries such as GSON as so far they don't keep the JSON in the same format as if I queried the mongo database using the generic Document type.

As a really simple example, my JSON has the _id and date properties like this, some entities will have nested child documents/types ...

```
{
        "questions": [
            {
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "605b3d62958763a2e18be480"
                },
                "companyId": {
                    "$oid": "554a0123c2e625bd02259318"
                },
                "groupId": null,
                "title": "Test Title 1",
                "desc": "Description 1",
                "style": "range",
                "minRange": 1,
                "maxRange": 10,
                "comments": false,
                "startDate": {
                    "$date": "2021-03-01T00:00:00Z"
                },
                "endDate": {
                    "$date": "2021-03-31T23:59:00Z"
                },
                "deleted": true,
                "frequencyMins": 1
            },
            ..
        ],
    }
}
```

Comment: "...they don't keep the JSON in the same format..."  The format is JSON.  Order of fields doesn't matter.

Comment: It looks like your JSON is an Extended JSON and can be imported into MongoDB as it is - using `mongoimport`. Then you can read from the database as _Document_ or a POJO (use codecs).

Comment: Thanks, but this is the JSON that was generated from Mongo by querying using the generic <Document> type.  I don't need mongoimport I can just use the SDK to add / update using the same or modified Document.  The issue is if I receive JSO from the mobile app and want to parse it to a POJO first (how?), or query from the DB as a POJO (instead of generic Document) to manipulate in a type-safe way BEFORE converting to a Document then JSON string?